# If two polynomials are close, is the location of their maximum close?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f$ and $g$ be polynomial of degree $n$ with domain $[-1,1]$
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i, \\
 g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n b_i x^i.
$$
If the polynomials are close to each other
$$
 \|f - g \|_\infty < \epsilon,
$$
and we let $x^*$ and $y^*$ be their respective maximum
$$
 x^* = \operatorname{argmax} f(x), \\
 y^* = \operatorname{argmax} g(x),
$$
is it true that $|x^* - y^*|$ is small?

Intuitively, this seems true, but I would like to see
a mathemetical quantification of the assertion.
The hypothesis that the polynomials are close
gives a global restriction on their oscillations.
But, to control the position of the maximum,
the closeness assumption seems insufficient.

If the closeness assumption is insufficient, what other assumption would make the assertion true?

Comment: `polynomial of degree n taking value in [−1,1]` What would be an example of such among (non-constant) polynomials?

Comment: Yeah... do you mean that the values are in $[-1,1]$, or that you're restricting your attention to the _domain_ $[-1,1]$?

Comment: $\|f-g\|_{\infty}\lt\epsilon$ directly gives you that $|x^* - y^*| \lt \epsilon$, does it not ?

Comment: thanks for pointing the typo: the domain is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: is the maximizer unique?

Comment: @LinAlg if assuming a unique maximizer helps to prove the assertion, I'm interested.

Comment: If I take two arbitrary polynomials $f$, $g$ I can choose small real numbers $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$  so that $\delta_1f$ and $\delta_2g$ are both $\epsilon/2$ close to the zero function on $[-1,1]$.  Hence $\delta_1f$ and $\delta_2g$ are $\epsilon$ close to one another, but their extrema are totally arbitrary (and the same as $f$ and $g$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} x$, $g(x) = -\frac{\varepsilon}{2} x$ (both restricted to $[-1,1]$. Then $||f(x)-g(x)|| \leq \epsilon$, while $||x^*-y^*||=2$.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true.

For instance, take your favorite polynomial that achieves the same maxima twice, in different locations: for example,
$$
p(x):=10-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2.
$$

This attains a maximum value of $10$, at both $x=\pm\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, let's modify $p(x)$ a little, in two different ways:
$$
p_1(x):=p(x)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}x,\qquad p_2(x):=p(x)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}x.
$$

These are both still polynomials, and their pointwise difference is at most $\epsilon$.  However, the maximum of $p_1$ occurs for $x$ a bit bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$, while the maximum for $p_2$ occurs for $x$ a bit smaller than $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $f(x)=-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\varepsilon\frac{x+1}{4}$ and $g(x)=-f(x)$. Then $||f-g||_\infty=\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon$ but $x^*=1$ and $y^*=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Consider a polynomial with tow equal absolute maxima, for example 
$$g(x)=x^2$$

Now define 
$$f(x)=h(x)+\frac{\epsilon}{2} x \\
g(x)=h(x)-\frac{\epsilon}{2} x \\
$$